# Intrinsic curvature calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature

Gauss theorem egregium says that it is possible for the inhabitants of a 2d surface to calculate the surface curvature without knowing that it is embedded in a 3d euclidean space, simply calculating distances and angles.

But, in order to calculate distances and angles they need a metric (related to their 2 curvilinear coordinates). How can they discover the proper metric if they cannot refer their curvilinear coordinates to the embedding euclidean space?

If possible, please make some example

Comment: They don't discover it. They are *given* the metric from the outset, along with being given the surface in some way.

Comment: @ted ok, but then how can they calculate distances and angles (to discover if they live on a curved space) if they are not given the metric from the outside?

Comment: They can't ... You need what I said to even talk about a Riemannian structure on a surface. The most basic example is the hyperbolic plane; it is not embedded in 3D Euclidean space.

Comment: @ted I must be missing something. 2D inhabitants can discover the curvature intrinsically (no need to ask to their 3D-embedding-friends) --> this is what Gauss remarkable theorem proves. But in order to perform the necessary measurements, they need a metric, and they must deduce it from outside as you said. So isn't it a circular reasoning? It seems to me  that these 2d inhabitants are not indipendent at all

Comment: Gauss's Theorema Egregium says that if you *know* the Riemannian metric (or first fundamental form), then you can compute the curvature — you don't need any other extrinsic data. I keep telling you that you need to be given the metric; it need *not* come from an embedding of the surface. I gave you the example of hyperbolic geometry, where you put the "abstract" metric $(dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy)/y^2$ on the upper half plane $H=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y>0\}$.